# Is there a way for SPSS to run through all possible GLMM given selected random effects and fixed effects and select the one with the lowest AIC?

Tags: r, spss, glmm

I was wondering if there was a way for SPSS to go through the various possible models which could be used given a data set, target, fixed effects, and random effects, and select which one had the lowest AIC? Or would I have to do this manually by gong through every possible combination? Or is there a way to do this in another statistical programme, like R?

I have been trying to just set up SPSS to do each variation one at a time and it is very time consuming.